# Why is the effect of a single data point on Pearson's r asymmetric?

Tags: regression, pearson-r

For the data (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4) and (5,c), where c can vary, it is clear that the value of Pearson's r in a simple linear regression will be 1 if and only if c = 5.

There is some interval of c values such that 0.9 < r < 1. My intuition was that this interval should be symmetric about c = 5, but this is not the case.

For a visualization of this asymmetry, see here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fsuxuchjp6 The red rectangle represents the interval. Slide the blue button the observe to change in the regression outputs. The interval is in fact (approximately) 2.9 < c < 10.2.

Why is this the case? Why is there more "room" for c to be larger than 5 while keeping r > 0.9?

Comment: Short, informal answer: because $c ≥ 4$ is concordant with the direction of relation in the rest of the data and $c < 4$ isn't.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I am still a little surprised by the lack of symmetry when $4<c<6.$